# How to register Arial Narrow as a basefont with Itext sharp

Tags: itext

I use the following statement to create a Arial Narrow basefont with iText Sharp.

```
   BaseFont arialn = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\Arial-narrow_[allfont.net].ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

This is how I use where cb2 is the content byte and f_cn2 is the base font.

The output is not Arial Narrow.

```
   cb2.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);  
   cb2.BeginText();
   cb2.SetFontAndSize(f_cn2, 10);
      foreach (var xy in xylist)
      {
        cb2.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, xy.Text, xy.xpos, xy.ypos, 0F);
      }
   cb2.EndText();
```

Comment: What font is it then?

Comment: Maybe `f_cn2` isn't the same as `arialn`. Maybe the font file isn't present in the font directory. Without more info, this question can't be answered.

Comment: The actual font printed is Arial just not Arial narrow.  f_cn2 is a parameter which arialn base font passed to.   I verified that Arialn.ttf is in the windows\fonts directory.  This is the actual statement the creates the base font.    BaseFont arialn = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\Arialn_0.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)

Comment: Problem resolved.   The font parameter was passed incorrectly.